# How can I make a div element "float" up when resizing the browser window using css and html?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this out, but am unable.  I am looking for a way (through coding html/css) to "float" a div element up as the browser window's width is decreased.

Here is the browser window at full width with the div elements side by side.

[image: Wide layout]

After resizing (decreasing browser window width), I'd like for the 2nd div element to "float" above the 1st div element.

[image: Narrow layout]

I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

UPDATE: First, thank you all for the help.  After reading/trying recommendations, I am looking for a solution that is functional across all browsers.  Also, the elements will be dynamic images.  And, it doesn't have to be strictly limited to html/css, but the most simplistic implementation is always appreciated! :)   Thank you again for your input and help.

Comment: Does those elements have a dynamic size?

Comment: Do you want the divs to be in the 1 2 order when in Full screen, or it doesn't matter what order. eg; 2 1

Comment: Mihey, I have added a comment to the original post.

Comment: Andre3wap - The order in full screen is 1 2, then 2 1 as the window decreases in width.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the second div first in your code like this:

```
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="first"></div>
```

And add `float: left;` attribute to the first div with CSS. You won't need jQuery for that:
http://jsbin.com/ERutocO/1/

Comment: This doesn't work in chrome and opera, only in FF (due to different float behaviour). It's safer to use `float: right` on both elements. If he needs them on the left side of the window, he can put them into a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Cedric for pointing this out.  And thanks p2kmgcl for your response.  I tried doing this is IE and the functionality doesn't work.  Both divs are stacked on top of each other regardless of window width.

Comment: I've just tested it on google chrome and works perfectly. With `float: right;` will also work, but the first div will get at the right if there's enough space.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put number 2 in front of number 1 in your html code, then use `float: right` on both of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/4sCrQ/

Comment: Votep up for the right sollution. I'm still not getting it, why the previous sugestion has 2 votes, when it isn't what @Aaron asked for!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only CSS answer then you will need to use CSS3's media queries which word depending on the screen type and its size!

Use this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px;) { // screen size 900px
  // if screen size 900px then position them here as
  .div1 { // first div
    margin: 10%; // margin
  }

  .div2 { // second div
    // whatever property
  }
}
```

And when the size decreases to lets say 500px width then

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { // if screen size is 500px
  .div1 { // first div
     // position it above,
   }

   .div2 { // second div!
    // position it below by using min-width attr, and by adding paddings..
   }
}
```

Good luck!

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries (Mozilla Developer's Network)

Comment: -1: solution is much more complex than necessary, and this is not true: `If you want only CSS answer then you will need to use CSS3's media queries`

Comment: He asked for CSS, so he would use this, however as my answer shows that the complexity is when the screen size is too low!

Comment: However, that line was to tell the OP that if you want an **CSS only** answer than **Media Query** would be best!

Comment: He asked for CSS **and** HTML. And: setting the `div 2` first in the html and floating it right will do what OP wants, won't it? Your answer is uselessly complicated, especially for a question by an OP who cannot even do simple CSS floats. (But thanks for contributing, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

Float the blue div left, the yellow div right. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W27kQ/)

```
#yellow {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
#blue {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd68e/)

While making this example some answers where posted here, and they are almost simular to my, so excuse me for duplication, but here is another possible solution.
I've reorder the div's and add `float: right;` instead of left.